# Pattern Matching in RXJava/RxAndroid

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

Can we do pattern matching in RXJava similar to other functional language?

Thanks,
Sumanta

Answer (score 0):

I think that we can use `boolean java.lang.String.matches(String regex)` applied with `filter()` operator; for example supposing that we need to count how many matches of a specific `PATTERN` there are in a list of `words`, we can do in this way:

```
private static final String PATTERN = "[q].*[A-Za-z]";

List<String> words = Arrays.asList("the","quick","brown","fox","jumped","over","the","lazy","dog");

Flowable.fromIterable(words)
        .filter(elem->elem.matches(PATTERN))
        .count()
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

And you get:

```
1
```